# mysql , make new user only can read current table ,and can insert & update to new table

Tags: mysql, database, sql-grant

There are five table in my database, now I create user1 , but I want this come true:

user1 only can read current five table.

user1 can create table, and insert & update to new table.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You should think about:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_db_name.table_1 to 'your_user_name'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_db_name.table_2 to 'your_user_name'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_db_name.table_3 to 'your_user_name'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_db_name.table_4 to 'your_user_name'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_db_name.table_5 to 'your_user_name'@'%';
```

Till now your_user_name has access to this five tables only.
Below Grant will allow to CREATE table in specified DB to "user_name"

```
GRANT CREATE ON db_name.* TO 'user_name'@'%';
```

Once the user created tables, then you have to update the permission as required.

```
GRANT CREATE ON db_name.* TO 'user_name'@'%';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON db_name.table_1 TO 'user_name'@'%';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON db_name.table_2 TO 'user_name'@'%';
```